# Script for automation in experimental setup

Tags: python

Good afternoon guys,

I am a python beginner and I am trying to implement the following script for generating an automatic list of commands to feed into a machine. The script now looks like:

```
print("re 1")
make_same = "xfb nc_proc 0"
first_exp = 1
exp_id = str(first_exp)
copy_par = "rpar re999"
next_please = "re " + exp_id


def macro_maker():
     parameters = [copy_par, make_same, next_please]
     for settings in parameters:
           print(settings)

macro_maker()

def repeat(f, n):
    for i in range(n):
        f()
repeat(macro_maker, 1)
```

I would like to modify it in a way that it automatically passes to the next experiment without my input. For example, the current output is:

```
re 1
rpar re999
xfb nc_proc 0
re 1
rpar re999
xfb nc_proc 0
re 1
```

While I would like to have the following output:

```
re 1
rpar re999
xfb nc_proc 0
re 2
rpar re999
xfb nc_proc 0
re 3
```

I tried to look up for similar questions for several days, but I only managed to come up with new errors every time!

Much love to anybody that can help me with this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem only comes from the fact that your `next_please` string is constant throughout the whole script. Therefore it always prints the same thing `'re 1'`.

From what I understand that's the only parameter that is meant to change, what you can do is this:

```py
make_same = "xfb nc_proc 0"
copy_par = "rpar re999"
next_please = "re {}"


def macro_maker(index):
     print(next_please.format(index))
     parameters = [copy_par, make_same]
     for settings in parameters:
           print(settings)

def repeat(f, n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        f(i)

repeat(macro_maker, 2)
```

`macro_maker` takes an experiment index and treat `next_please` differently from all other parameters, feeding it the current index to format the template string `"re {}"`.